# Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли составлено предложение: «Текст статьи может приводиться в запросе не полностью, а указываются лишь те части, по которым квалифицировано содеянное»?

Answer (score 3):

Предложение построено неправильно.
Всё дело в формуле "не..., а...", которая предполагает противопоставление или однородных членов, или в целом простых предложений в составе сложносочинённого предложения: ср.: *Не ты, а я должен сказать ему правду  (*противопоставлены однородные подлежащие*). Не место красит человека, а человек место* (противопоставлены простые предложения). 
В Вашем примере формула "не..., а..." предложена, но используется она некорректно. Отрицание "не" в первом простом предложении относится только к обстоятельству "не полностью". Значит, противительный союз "а" должен присоединять однородное ему обстоятельство  (к примеру,"частично"). В нашем примере присоединяется целое предложение. Таким образом, грамматические нормы в этом предложении нарушены. Правка, предложенная behemothus, мне кажется удачной.

Comment: Не, на грамматический огрех это не нятен.
"Все дело" в том, что здесь может и не быть "формулы". "В огороде не бузина, а в Киеве дядька" - где здесь ваша формула?  
Или еще проще - уберите "может" и все станет даже стилистически безупречтым: @Текст статьи приводится в запросе не полностью, а указа,n лишь те части, по которым квалифицировано содеянное".  
Повторяю, в конкретном примере дело только в модальности первой части и отсутствии такой модальности во второй.

Comment: Алогизм в известной поговорке "В огороде бузина, а в Киеве дядька" приводит к желаемому комическому эффекту. Это излюбленный приём юмористов. Там, кстати, нет "не". Впрочем, Ваш пример с "не" как раз похож на предложенный автором, та же ошибка. Предложение "Текст статьи приводится в запросе не полностью, а указывают лишь те части, по которым квалифицировано содеянное" тоже требует правки.

Comment: Разумеется, в оригинале там нет нет. Я специально изменил её под нашу тему. Но так и не понял в чем же ошибка. В измененном варианте, разумеется.

*Холодной воды вчера не было, а горячую уже две недели как отключили.*  
*Вчера я смотрел не эту передачу, а брат вообще спал.* 
и проч.
*Иванов у нас работает не на полную ставку, а Петрова давно уволили*.
Неужели везде ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Тут шероховатось с неличными формами. Хотя вроде бы можно и так, но как-то косноязычно получается. Если первая часть с "может", то и вторая требует какой-то модальности.

Я бы помннял на   
*«Текст статьи может приводиться в запросе не полностью, достаточно указать лишь те части, по которым квалифицировано содеянное»*

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал лишь небольшую правку, чтобы убрать грамматическую ошибку в строении этого предложения: "Текст статьи может приводиться в запросе не полностью, а с указанием лишь тех частей, по которым квалифицировано содеянное».

Answer (score 0):

Нужно писать "а с указанием содеянного"